# Why is "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT" null?

Tags: c#

I'm playing around with `HostBuilder` class and I need to get the current environment to properly configure the app. Right now `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` is `null` when I run the app with `dotnet run`, but it should be `Development`. What am I missing here?

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

var HostBuilder = new HostBuilder();

HostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
{
  var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT");
  builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
  builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
  if (environment is not null)
  {
    builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json");
  }
});

HostBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
  var configuration = context.Configuration;
  Console.WriteLine($"Key1 from appsettings.Development.json: {configuration["Key1"]}");
  Console.WriteLine($"Key2 from appsettings.Production.json: {configuration["Key2"]}");
  Console.WriteLine($"Key3 from appsettings.Staging.json: {configuration["Key3"]}");
  // ...
});

var Host = HostBuilder.Build();
```

Comment: How did you set the environment variable? It's not if it's not set.

Comment: @fredrik, I did not set it. I guess, that's the issue.

Comment: @fredrik, is there an environment variable set automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set/ add the `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` variable to your `appsettings.json` file. At this moment your code cant find `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` since it doesn't exist in base C#.

Comment: @rbdeek, if I understand correctly, the value in the `appsettings.json` would be hardcoded and I would have to change it every time I want to run the app in a different environment? Like, before creating a production build I would have to change the value to **Production** in the `appsettings.json`?

Comment: Normally you would implement the switching in a build pipeline. But yes you would have to do that by hand. I would recommend having a file for each stage of the code development. for example: local, dev, staging, production. you would have 4 appsettings but this will allow you to make easy changes mid developing

Comment: Setting DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT in appsettings.json wouldn't make OP's code work. OP is using the result of `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")` to determine which appSettings.[something].json to use.

Comment: Yes that is right but i don't think it is possible for your code to know what stage of development it is without being told externally

Comment: Exactly, so OP needs to set `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` as an environment variable.